# Bash shell script executing out of order when passed over stdin to LXC container

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, lxc

I am passing the following simple shell script to bash on an LXC container:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install postgresql -y

sudo -u postgres psql -c 'create database dvdrental;'
```

The actual command I'm using to run it is:

```
cat sample.sh | lxc-attach -n test-container -- /bin/bash
```

The reason I'm doing it this way instead of uploading the script into the container and executing that way is that this is just the proof of concept for a much more complex application we're building that has to take commands over stdin and run them in the container.

It seems to work great, except for one thing. It moves onto the `psql` command while postgresql is still installing, i.e.,

```
[...]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main ssl-cert all 1.0.33 [16.6 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main postgresql-common all 154ubuntu1 [103 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main postgresql-9.3 amd64 9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04 [2,669 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main postgresql all 9.3+154ubuntu1 [5,038 B]
Fetched 5,834 kB in 28s (207 kB/s)                                             
Preconfiguring packages ...

    sudo -u postgres psql -c 'create database dvdrental;'
Selecting previously unselected package libroken18-heimdal:amd64.
(Reading database ... 14599 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libroken18-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64.
[...]
```

Note the existence of the `sudo -u postgres psql -c 'create database dvdrental;'` line in the middle of the output. Interestingly it always shows up right after the downloading portion of the apt-get command is completed...

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ooooh, this is a *fun* one.

The short answer: it happens there because apt (or something it forks) is reading stdin at that point in its execution, and it reads the remaining lines of the script because that's what is still sitting in stdin at that point.  The short fix: put `</dev/null` at the end of the `apt-get install` line, and move on with your day.

The long answer (seriously, this is a biggun): there is nothing special about stdin/stdout/stderr, from the point of view of a running process.  They're just file descriptors, and file descriptors are shared between processes when they're forked.  So, what happens (more-or-less) is:

1. The copy of bash running interactively in your terminal opens a new `pipe`(2), then forks a new process, which closes the existing stdout, and  then makes the stdout file descriptor (1) the writer end of the pipe (see `dup2`(2)).  That child process then `exec`s `cat sample.sh`, which reads the file and writes it to what it *thinks* is stdout (but is actually the writer end of a pipe).
2. The copy of bash running interactively in your terminal forks another new process, this time closing the existing *stdin*, and then makes the stdin file descriptor (0) the reader end of the same pipe discussed previously (again, with a call to `dup2`).  This process then `exec`s your `lxc-attach` process.

   If nothing interferes with stdin along the way (which it doesn't, in this particular case) then *every* process which is forked from the one which got the reader end of the pipe as stdin will *also* have that exact same file descriptor, attached to the same pipe, which had the contents of `sample.sh` stuffed into it, as its stdin.  *Any* process which reads from that file descriptor will now have consumed the bytes read, and no other process which reads from that file descriptor will get those specific bytes.  Take careful note of this; you will see this material again.
3. When the bash at the far end of your Italian water-closet-style plumbing extravaganza finally gets going, it will read "some" of the data from the pipe which is its stdin (because that's what bash does, when called without arguments and without a tty as stdin).  Through the magic of `strace`, I've just confirmed that bash does actually read its input one character at a time (rather than reading it in, say, 4k chunks), so every individual character that isn't part of a command that bash has, or is currently, executing, will still be sitting in the pipe-which-bash-has-as-its-stdin.
4. When bash executes the second command in your script, `apt-get install` tra la la, it forks a new process.  Which inherits all the file descriptors of bash, *including* (most importantly) *our good friend the pipe-which-is-stdin*.  This then also happens for any processes which `apt-get` forks (which is, let me assure you, quite a lot).  One of those, or `apt-get` itself, is deciding to read stdin and write whatever it reads to stdout (or possibly stderr).
5. When the `apt-get install` finishes, bash finds out what the next thing to execute is by reading from stdin once more.  Because something *else* already read everything out of the pipe, though, there's nothing left, and bash figures "oh well, I guess I'm done then" and exits.  Again, the pipe is empty because something else already read it dry, and everything that shares a single file descriptor shares the bounty from it.

The solution to the "shared stdin" problem is, unsurprisingly, to stop passing stdin around like a bong at a frat party.  Since you can't stop `fork`(2) from automatically giving everyone the same file descriptors, you need to tell bash, instead, to give `apt-get` (and anything else taking an illicit sip from that sweet, sweet pipe) something *else* to toke on, instead.  The easiest thing to give is `/dev/null` -- that ever-faithful, never-full, source of all your "Dave's not here, man" delights.  That is the domain of "input redirection", which is what the `</dev/null` does -- it says, "hey bash, before you `exec` that `apt-get`, swap out stdin (file descriptor 0) with the file descriptor you get from opening `/dev/null`".

An exercise for the reader, to finish off: try putting `</dev/zero` after the `apt-get install` command, and explain why what happens happens.

Comment: That has got to be *the* funniest answer I've ever read! Alas, you're also correct. Is there a better way to take code that we get as a string and programmatically run it in an LXC container?

Comment: Short of having the command that `lxc-attach` runs capture the input to a file then point bash at that (eg `lxc-attach -n foo -- /bin/bash -c 'cat >/tmp/script; . script'`) I don't know of a way to do it.  I tried playing around with shell-level input redirection, but `exec </dev/null` terminates the shell, and all `exec <&-` did was cause bash to segfault.  Whoops...

Comment: Oh, dirty hack alert: assuming that your script isn't too long, you can do: `cat script.sh | lxc-attach -n foo -- bash <(cat)`.  In this case, the `<(cat)` will hoover up the first few kB in `stdin` before `apt-get` gets its hands on it, and then put it into a separate file descriptor for bash to read out at its leisure.

Comment: Here's another one: `exec 42<script.sh; lxc-attach -n foo -- bash /dev/fd/42 </dev/null`.  This one won't have any problems with script length.

Comment: OK, enough playing around with bash file descriptor handling.  Back to documenting Ruby code.  Let me know if any of those helps you out, @Soviero.

Comment: Another possible workaround: wrap the entire script in `{ ... }` (be sure to put the close brace on its own line, or precede it with `;`). This forces the shell to read & parse the entire script (to match up the braces) before running any of the commands in it. Warning: if you use this trick and include anything after the close bracket, *that* will be read by the `apt-get` etc commands, and anyone trying to figure out why will be even more confused than you were to start with.

Comment: Oooh, that's a neat hack, too.